# Convert French date String to date Object PHP Laravel OctoberCms

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I would like to convert a String date to an Object date.

String date :

```
jeu. 26 avril 2018 10:25
```

to this object date

```
{ ["date"]=> string(26) "2018-04-26 10:34:50.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(12) "Africa/Tunis" }
```

so far i've tried :

```
Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d H:i:s", 'jeu. 26 avril 2018 10:25')
```

i've got an exception :

> Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. The separation symbol
>   could not be found Data missing

Comment: Can you give another example? like `jeu. 26 avril 2018 10:25`

Comment: maybe `mar. 26 mars 2018 10:25`, mars is the day name in French and mars is the month name in french. i've tried  `Carbon::createFromFormat("D. d M Y H:i", 'jeu. 26 avril 2018 10:25') `, but it did not recognize the french local

Comment: `mar.` & `jeu.` are creating the problem here.  I have solution for the string like `26 mars 2018 10:25`

Answer (score 3):

u have to change the format:

```
Carbon::createFromFormat("D. d M Y H:i", 'jeu. 26 avril 2018 10:25')
```

Note: i assume `jeu` is day name.

Comment: Thanks, `jeu` is a day name in French ,i've tried your'e code,  now i have another exception `A textual day could not be found Unexpected data found.`

Comment: its not recognising french text. but for english text it works

Answer (score 0):

You need to set locale and proper wildcard characters to read proper date format

> You can find placeholder here when working with locale : http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

this code should work

```
<?php      
// use this only if you working on other locale want to restore OLD locale back
// ====================================
    $oldLocale = setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
    var_dump(setlocale(LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')); 
// ^ this must return 'fr_FR' then only we confirm locale is set
// if return FALSE then install 'fr_FR' locale for PHP on server 
// ====================================


// day name will be having .(dot) at end according abbreviation 
// lun., mar., mer., jeu., ven., sam., dim.

$timeChunks = strptime('jeu. 26 avril 2018 10:25', '%a %d %b %Y %H:%M');    

// ====================================    
// use this only if you working on other locale want to restore OLD locale 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $oldLocale);
// ====================================

$date = Carbon::create( 
    ($timeChunks['tm_year'] + 1900) , // year
    ($timeChunks['tm_mon'] + 1), // month
    $timeChunks['tm_mday'],  // day
    $timeChunks['tm_hour'],  // hour
    $timeChunks['tm_min'],  // min
    $timeChunks['tm_sec'] // second
);
// tm_year starts from 1900 so we need to add it
// tm_mon is 0 to 11 so add 1

var_dump($date);
```

if any doubts then please comment